# Design ideas for a versioned db schema with related tables also versioned

Tags: sql-server-2005, schema, versioning

Here is the drill, I want to version a database.  I have done this before using multiple rows where the table primary key becomes a combination of the row id and either a datestamp or a version #.

Now I want to version a table that depends on many other small tables.  Versioning each table will be a giant PITA, so I am looking for good options to verion a schema where the data to be versioned spreads over multiple tables.

All related tables are properly keyed with foreign key relationships. The database is currently on Sql Server 2005.